# PostgreSQL select all from one table and join count from table relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, psql

I have two tables, `post_categories` and `posts`. I'm trying to `select * from post_categories;`, but also return a temporary column with the count for each time a post category is used on a post.

**Posts**

```
| id | name | post_category_id |
| 1  | test | 1                |
| 2  | nest | 1                |
| 3  | vest | 2                |
| 4  | zest | 3                |
```

**Post Categories**

```
| id | name  |
| 1  | cat_1 |
| 2  | cat_2 |
| 3  | cat_3 |
```

Basically, I'm trying to do this without subqueries and with joins instead. Something like this, but in real `psql`.

`select * from post_categories some-type-of-join posts, count(*)`

Resulting in this, ideally.

```
| id | name  | count |
| 1  | cat_1 | 2     |
| 2  | cat_2 | 1     |
| 3  | cat_3 | 1     |
```

Your help is greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a derived table that contains the counts per `post_category_id` and left join it to the `post_categories` table

```
select p.*, coalesce(t1.p_count,0)
from post_categories p
left join (
    select post_category_id, count(*) p_count
    from posts
    group by post_category_id
) t1 on t1.post_category_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select post_categories.id, post_categories.name , count(posts.id)  
from post_categories 
inner join posts 
on post_category_id  =  post_categories.id  
group by post_categories.id, post_categories.name
```

Comment: Perhaps your table name is not exactly `post_categories` :(

Comment: It is unfortunately :/

Comment: If there are any other columns than post_categories.id, post_categories.name, you must also use them in an aggregate function.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Answer updated. And going to sleep :)